# Replace value in config.xml for cordova by powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, cordova

i have task for change configuration for cordova when its build. I must change value of APP_SECRET in two sections. One for android application and one for ios application. These case uses in azure devops pipeline and these parameters must change when project builds
XML is:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="14" id="com.someaapp.com" ios-CFBundleVersion="0" version="2.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>testApp</name>
    <description>
        Test App
    </description>
    <author email="" href="">
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="80000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="APP_SECRET" value="7bae78da-eeb7-4r7d-a7bf-c6r3ffdg03fc" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xxxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="APP_SECRET" value="fffdffdge16-39ee-485b-bsdfd-4aecf25c5891" />
        <config-file parent="NSAppTransportSecurity" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <false />
            </dict>
        </config-file>
        <icon height="1024" src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="res/screens/ios/Default-x.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="1792" src="res/screens/ios/Default-xr.png" width="828" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <feature name="UniversalAnalytics">
        <param name="ios-package" value="UniversalAnalyticsPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <engine name="android" spec="^8.0.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-exitapp-ios" spec="0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-msal" spec="file:cordova-plugins\cordova-plugin-msal">
        <variable name="MSAL_APP_ID_INPUT" value="BLANK" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="5.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen-iphonex-support" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics" spec="^0.5.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appcenter-crashes" spec="^0.5.1" />
</widget>
```

I use these code to change value:

```
$filePathToTask = "D:\Downloads\config.xml"
[xml]$config = Get-Content $filePathToTask
$value = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter new APP_SECRET: '
$node = $config.widget.platform.preference
$node.SetAttribute("value", "$value");
$config.Save($filePathToTask)
```

But its chenge all values in xml, how i can do change APP_SECRET valuas in android and ios section, they must be diferent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the node more to only change the values of the nodes with name 'APP_SECRET'.

Also, I would advise to save the updated config file with a new name so (at least while testing) you do not overwrite your original.

```
$configIn  = 'D:\Downloads\config.xml'
$configOut = 'D:\Downloads\config2.xml'

[xml]$config = Get-Content $configIn -Raw

$secret = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter new APP_SECRET: '

$config.widget.platform.preference | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'APP_SECRET' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.SetAttribute("value", $secret)
    }

$config.Save($configOut)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks, you help me, done my task by these:

`$value = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter new APP_SECRET: '
$filePathToTask = "D:\config.xml"
[xml]$config = Get-Content $filePathToTask
$platform = $config.widget.platform | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'android' }
$node = $platform.preference | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'APP_SECRET' }
$node.SetAttribute("value", "$value");
$config.Save($filePathToTask)`